# Proving differentiability at 0

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$  be defined by

\begin{align*}
h(x) =
\begin{cases} 
\sin(x^2)\cos(1/x) & x\neq 0 \\
0 &  x=0 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Prove that $h$ is differentiable at $0$ and find $h'(0)$.

So far I have used
\begin{align*}
h'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x) - h(0)}{x - 0}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Start with the definition of derivative:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{h(x) - h(0)}{x - 0} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^{2})\cos(1/x)}{x}
\end{align*}

Now observe that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}} = 1\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to0}x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?